# TypeError: method()takes in 1 positional argument but 2 were given (Python and Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to use a function inside my py file to change screens after a certain number of seconds, these are the 2 screens and the ScreenManager(although not all the code,shortened it to the important bits):

```
class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Buttons(Screen):

    def change_screen(self):
        WindowManager.current = "start_screen"


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.fullscreen = "auto"
    MyApp().run()
```

and this is the whole kv file:

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

WindowManager:
    transition: NoTransition()

    StartScreen:
    Buttons:


<StartScreen>:
    name: "start_screen"

    Button:
        background_normal: "maxresdefault.jpg"
        background_down: "maxresdefault.jpg"
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
        pos_hint: {"x": .35, "y": .35}
        text: "Play"
        font_size: 250
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "btn_screen"
            root.reset_score()


<Buttons>:
    name: "btn_screen"
    btn: btn
    on_enter:
        Clock.schedule_once(root.change_screen, 5)

    Button:
        background_normal: "pepe11.png"
        background_down: "pepe11.png"
        id: btn
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.3
        pos_hint: {"x": .4, "y": .35}
        on_press:
            root.respawn()
```

and so my problem is with the Clock.schedule_once command I try to call when entering the Buttons screen, I just keep getting "TypeError: change_screen() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: try changing `def change_screen(self):` to `def change_screen(self, *args):`

Comment: Tried it, both with dt and *args, but now it doesn't do anything, it just stays at the current screen, but at least I got rid of the error, would you know if I need to add something more? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

1. [`Clock.schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once) passes as an argument the time interval to the callback so you must pass an additional parameter.
2. `WindowManager.current` is not valid because `current` is not a static attribute so you must access it through an object, in the Screen case you can access the `ScreenManager` that manages it through the [`manager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.manager) property.

So the solution is:

```py
# ...
class Buttons(Screen):
    def change_screen(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = "start_screen"
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) uses the `dt` argument (delta-time) for the callback function.
You have to change your function like this:

```
def change_screen(self, dt):
    WindowManager.current = "start_screen"
```

Comment: Ty, I tried that and its better now, not getting any errors but now It just stays on the current Buttons screen and doesn't do anything, would I also need to edit something in my kv file alongside the argument?